# Not listed in lsusb but listed in adb devices

Tags: ubuntu, adb

On Ubuntu, is it possible to have an Android device connected with USB that isn't listed by `lsusb` but is listed by `adb devices`?

Comment: it's uncommon for an android device not to have any interfaces enumerated at all. my guess is that the device is listed by `lsusb` but you did not recognize it. there are a few things you could check - http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-most-comprehensive-write-up-on-how.html

Comment: @AlexP. Thanks. In case `lsusb` didn't list the Android device, can it be listed by `adb devices` or is it impossible?

Comment: this might be possible if your device is connected in `tcpip` mode. but more likely you just did not recognize your device in `lsusb` output. Have you read the whole article I linked?

Comment: @AlexP. Yes I read your webpage, thanks a lot for pointing to it it's very informative. Let's assume that the Android device connected with USB (i.e. no `tcpip` though Ethernet or Wi-Fi). My understanding is as follows: since the adb binary uses low level `libusb` library to access the device, and `lsusb` uses the same `libusb` library to list connected USB devices, then in case `lsusb` didn't list the Android device,  it is impossible for `adb devices` to list Android device. Did I get it right?

Comment: you got it right. but a small disclaimer: all my claims about `adb` inner workings are based on the original version provided by Google. My understanding is that you are using the version which comes with AppInventor. But most importantly - you are ignoring my main advice for you - to take a closer look at `lsusb` output. Do a `lsusb -v` and put it on pastebin

Comment: @AlexP. Thanks, actually I use the ADB that comes with Genymotion (because AppInventor's is outdated). I don't have the Android device anymore that was invisible to USB (if I do again I'll post the `lsusb -v` output). Thanks again for your help: could please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?